# How to measure runtime in web.py?

Tags: python, web.py, web-frameworks

I created a python webserver with web.py.
This webserver works fine. But I will get the infromation how long the webserver needs to get the result from the database and send it back to the client.

Can I realize that with the modul timeit?
Does someone has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`web.profiler`](http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/api#web.http) middleware to display some profiling information within each response.

```
application = web.application(urls, globals(), web.profiler)
```

If that information isn't enough, you could use [`cProfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#module-cProfile) to run your app and this will give you more detailed information.

```
import cProfile
cProfile.run("application.run()")
```

Comment: I use now web.profiler but nothing changed? Is it more than these two lines?

Comment: @Moehre You should see profiling information at the bottom of the web page when you view it.

Comment: Do you mean inside my html document? so I can see some time information in the consol of the devoloping tools. but I only wanna measure time inside te webserver. If I set _application.run(web.profiler)_ the content of the website is not shown anymore...

Comment: If I do the other way you wrote this error occured _AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'run'_

Comment: If I add web.profiler like this way: _app = web.application(urls, globals(), web.profiler)_ it works . I can see the time!

Comment: @Moehre Sorry I had to step away from the computer real quick. I will update my answer!